# How to call this retrofit method every hour?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

How do I call this method every hour since I am passing token value and taking the data from the api I want to get the data and pass it into another method because of that reason I want to call this actualData method every 1 hour or 5 minutes. I tried Handler but I cannot access the data from the api also I thought of using alarmmanager but I don't have any idea about how to implement it to this retrofit method!

Is there any way?

```
public void actualData(String tokenValue) {
        Call<ActualData> call2 = mapiPass.actualData("Bearer " + tokenValue);
        call2.enqueue(new Callback<ActualData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ActualData> call, Response<ActualData> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                           **data taken from the api**
                            }  
                        }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ActualData> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

This is what I have got when I used Handler.

> Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/LoadedApk;->rewriteRValues(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;I)V (greylist, linking, allowed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use worker manager. For Examples, Please follow the documentation.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics